# Getting the last created item selection

Tags: python, maya

I run a command in which it creates a new camera, however at the end of the said function, there is no selection nor does the function selects the object after it has run its course.
So are there any commands in which I could possible query for the last created item?

I tried using `cmds.listHistory' but that will only shows you results if there is already a selection..

Any ways in which I can get around with it?

Additionally, say I am using the following command using the

```
cameraShape...
aaa = "cameraShape1"
mel.eval('<Some mel-based command> cameraShape.transformX cameraShape.transformY cameraShape.transformZ;')
```

but when I tried writing that command in another way such as :
`mel.eval('<Some mel-based command> %s.transformX %s.transformY %s.transformZ;' %aaa)`

I got an error saying

```
# Error: not enough arguments for format string
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string #
```

Where am I writing it wrong exactly? I tried writing like `%aaa, aaa, aaa` still the same error occurs

Comment: @galaxyan That works... It seems that I am missing the `()` or I am writing it as `%aaa, %aaa, %aaa`.. Mistake on my part

Comment: lol. not a problem

Comment: @galaxyan just wondering if you have any ideas of getting the latest created node?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just stuff the new camera into a variable instead of relying on selection?

```
new_camera, new_camera_shape = cmds.camera()
```

---

You're not using the right syntax when formatting with `%`:

```
"My name is %s" % "Jon Snow" # Works for single
"My name is %s and I was born in %s" % ("Jon Snow", "Winterfell") # Multiple
```

Personally I prefer `format()` as it's suppose to be more forward compatible for Python 3:

```
"My name is {0} and I was born in {1}".format("Jon Snow", "Winterfell")
```

---

Detect new objects:

```
scene_before = cmds.ls(l=True, transforms=True)

# Run command to import object here

scene_after = cmds.ls(l=True, transforms=True)

new_objs = list( set(scene_after).difference(scene_before) )
```

Comment: Hi there, I am using `camera` as an example, perhaps that is a very bad example. The code for the creation of that object of mine is something like this - `import thisModule; thisModule.createItem()` and as such, after that code execution, it will create the object while leaving no selection at all, hence I have asked if it is possible to use some ways to select the latest created node.

Comment: Are you able to post that module's method? The method doesn't return the object it creates? Right off the bat I can think of a few ways to get the object. One cheap way is to create a list of all the objects in the scene BEFORE running the command, then compare it with a new list to get the new objects. This can be done using Python's set.difference. you can also you Maya API's MSceneMessage callbacks to get any new object. Since your post is a bit vague it's hard to direct you to a specific approach.

Comment: Say the command is - `import createCam; createCam.newNode()` apparently in the newNode() function, it has another function within and is calling that function - eg. createNewCam()...
While createNewCam() does have a return, but newNode() do not have. Is that a cause for concern or perhaps it is just me not knowing how to grab such return values...

FYI, this createCam was not done by me, it was an in-house thing..

Comment: The easiest solution would be to directly use `createNewCam`, but that might not be possible if the other function is doing additional setup to the node. This sounds like it may be bad code though. I posted an example of how you can get the new object. The idea is to compare the state of the scene objects before and after calling your function. To avoid callbacks I usually do this kind of approach for stuff like importing a new reference. And for the record, try to never rely on selection as it's bad practice. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the last created object. You can create a class that contain a variable history where your append in your other script the last object created.

```
class History:
    idCounter = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        History.idCounter.append(name)
        print(History.idCounter)

for name in ['nana', 'tata', 'zaza']:
    objectCreated = History(name)
```

Comment: Is there a simple way of doing it so? without creating additional classes

Comment: For me, the class is the easy way. If you want to go with something messy, yoiu could go with maya scriptjob or api callbacks. If you look to maya scriptJob, you can see that the event 'DagObjectCreated'  exists. It may your solution but I think it is a really dangerous way. i.e. think you will be some kind of new stack of history, it can be really heavy. With the class you can filter whatever you want, it takes 5 lines of code instead of... a lot....

Comment: Now that I re-read the comment, I'm afraid that you may have misunderstood what I mean. What I want is to get the selection of the latest created node and not keep the selection of the last created node.

Comment: Could you have a more concrete example ? I've read the comment of Green Cell and I think we are both confused by your post. My example doesn't select something but create a stack of history. I assumed that you have the control on the proc and make some return or modify it adding your proper classes. If you have to wrap yourself around other proc, use API Callbacks.

Comment: Please check out the comment I have written to Green Cell. The code itself, I am unable modify it as it is not my code nor do I have the permission

Comment: Okay, so if I understand. Go with Green Cell solution : do "all01 = cmds.ls()", you will get all the nodes of your scene. Do the camera command and then do "all02 = cmds.ls()" again. Substract all01 from all02  with python set() and you will get "the last nodes created". Or if you feel trickier, go as we said both, use Api Callbacks or Maya Scriptjob. The best way would be to ask to the owner a class property or a function as "createCam.getCamera()"